# In R Shiny, possible to use multiple conditions in conditional panel?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below MWE code, the two tabs generated by running the code, "Liabilities module" and "Interest rates", are identical. They are intended as two different paths to the same data table and plots (showing rates) currently generated by running the code.

But these 2 tabs need to diverge as they further develop, in terms of other action buttons in the sidebar panel and in terms of the action buttons appearing at the top of the main panels for each of the respective tabs. For sake of easy example, I'd like to add a "Test" action button to the "Liabilities module" but not to the "Interest rates" module.

How would I add multiple conditions to a conditional panel, so in this case "Test" action button appears in "Liabilities module" but not in "Interest rates" tabs? As shown in the image at the bottom.

My humble attempt to do this is marked # ATTEMPT # in the below MWE; naturally, it doesn't work so I had to comment it out.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x, matrix4Input) {
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix4Input,
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(
      extend = FALSE,
      names = FALSE,
      editableNames = FALSE
    ),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x, y) {
  a <- rep(y, x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)
}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  plot(
    w[, 1],
    sapply(w[, 2], function(x)
      gsub("%", "", x)),
    main = x,
    xlab = y,
    ylab = z
  )
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model..."),
  sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(
    strong("Base Input Panel")
  ))), uiOutput("Panels")),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "Liabilities module",
      value = 4,
      fluidRow(
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "showRates4",
          label = h5(strong(helpText(
            "Select model output to view:"
          ))),
          choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
          selected = 'Rates values',
          inline = TRUE
        ),
        uiOutput('showTab4Results')
      )
    ),
    # close tab panel
    tabPanel(
      "Interest rates",
      value = 5,
      fluidRow(
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "showRates5",
          label = h5(strong(helpText(
            "Select model output to view:"
          ))),
          choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
          selected = 'Rates values',
          inline = TRUE
        ),
        uiOutput('showTab5Results')
      )
    ),
    # close tab panel
    id = "tabselected"
  ))
) # close tabset panel, main panel, page with sidebar

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  matrix4   <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate  <-
    function() {
      vectorBaseRate(60, input$matrix4[1, 1])
    } # Must remain in server section
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates'),
      # ATTEMPT # condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test','Test')
    ) # close conditional panel
  }) # close renderUI
  
  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){DF <- NULL}
    else {
      if (input$modRates < 1) {DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = 0.2)}
      else {
        req(input$matrix4)
        DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = baseRate()[, 2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    DF
  }) # close reactive
  
  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session, 'matrix4', matrix4Default)})
  
  output$table5 <- output$table4 <- renderTable({vectorRates()})
  
  output$graph5 <- output$graph4 <- renderPlot({
    vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(), "A Variable", "Period", "Rate")
  })
  
  output$showTab4Results <- renderUI({
    if (input$showRates4 == 'Rates values'){tableOutput("table4")} 
    else {plotOutput("graph4")}
  })
  
  output$showTab5Results <- renderUI({
    if (input$showRates5 == 'Rates values'){tableOutput("table5")} 
    else {plotOutput("graph5")}
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   matrix4Input("matrix4", if (is.null(input$matrix4))
                     matrix4Default
                     else
                       input$matrix4),
                   useShinyjs(),
                   footer = tagList(
                     actionButton("resetRatesStruct", "Reset"),
                     modalButton("Close")
                   )
                 ))
               } # close modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another `conditionalPanel` using a different condition.

Furthermore I dropped all `renderUI`'s as it is not necessary to create conditionalPanels on the server side. This should result in a faster UI.

I added some more buttons to show the concept:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x, matrix4Input) {
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix4Input,
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(
      extend = FALSE,
      names = FALSE,
      editableNames = FALSE
    ),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x, y) {
  a <- rep(y, x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)
}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  plot(
    w[, 1],
    sapply(w[, 2], function(x)
      gsub("%", "", x)),
    main = x,
    xlab = y,
    ylab = z
  )
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model..."),
  sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(
    strong("Base Input Panel")
  ))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates')
  ), # close conditional panel
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test1','Test')
  )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test2','A mainPanel test button')
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabselected==5", actionButton('test3','Another mainPanel test button')
    ),
    tabsetPanel(
      selected = 4,
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test4','A tabsetPanel test button')
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.tabselected==5", actionButton('test5','Another tabsetPanel test button')
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Liabilities module",
        value = 4,
        fluidRow(
          radioButtons(
            inputId = "showRates4",
            label = h5(strong(helpText(
              "Select model output to view:"
            ))),
            choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
            selected = 'Rates values',
            inline = TRUE
          ),
          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.showRates4 == 'Rates values'", tableOutput("table4")),
          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.showRates4 == 'Rates plots'", plotOutput("graph4"))
        )
      ),
      # close tab panel
      tabPanel(
        "Interest rates",
        value = 5,
        fluidRow(
          radioButtons(
            inputId = "showRates5",
            label = h5(strong(helpText(
              "Select model output to view:"
            ))),
            choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
            selected = 'Rates values',
            inline = TRUE
          ),
          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.showRates5 == 'Rates values'", tableOutput("table5")),
          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.showRates5 == 'Rates plots'", plotOutput("graph5"))
        )
      ),
      # close tab panel
      id = "tabselected"
    ))
) # close tabset panel, main panel, page with sidebar

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  matrix4   <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate  <- function() {
    vectorBaseRate(60, input$matrix4[1, 1])
  } # Must remain in server section
  
  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){DF <- NULL}
    else {
      if (input$modRates < 1) {DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = 0.2)}
      else {
        req(input$matrix4)
        DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = baseRate()[, 2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    DF
  }) # close reactive
  
  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session, 'matrix4', matrix4Default)})
  
  output$table5 <- output$table4 <- renderTable({vectorRates()})
  
  output$graph5 <- output$graph4 <- renderPlot({
    vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(), "A Variable", "Period", "Rate")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   matrix4Input("matrix4", if (is.null(input$matrix4))
                     matrix4Default
                     else
                       input$matrix4),
                   useShinyjs(),
                   footer = tagList(
                     actionButton("resetRatesStruct", "Reset"),
                     modalButton("Close")
                   )
                 ))
               } # close modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, you also show how to add additional buttons in the different possible places which is exactly where I'm going with this. Also you show how you can have multiple conditional panels for the same "condition =". Works in the UI section. To do this in renderUI, I post another answer (I fiddled with it more) where you can nest conditional panels. Reason I rendered panels in server section using renderUI was to stop this weird flash-by when 1st invoking the App. But I'll try your suggestion of moving conditional panels back to UI & see if there's still invocation flashing.

Comment: In my experience using consitionalPanel is the most responsive solution to introduce conditional UI elements. With `renderUI` you need to wait for the Server and all the necessary communication to finish. I haven't seen any flashing in the apps I made so far.

Comment: I'm converting my not-MWE code over as you recommend, eliminating renderUI and moving all conditional panels to UI section. It certainly flows better and makes more sense intuitively. I'll check for invocation flashing in the not-MWE code (I am seeing it already) and will post that code to see if there's another way to tackle Shiny invocation flashing. RenderUI does impose some limits and glad to move away from it!

Comment: Sounds good - let me know if you have a MWE showing that flashing issue. Cheers

Comment: I'm done moving all conditional panels from server to UI section, eliminating renderUI and its complexities in the complete module this MWE was extracted from. No invocation flashing! At least for this "Liabilities" module. I'm going to try the same modifications for another related module, hopefully no invocation flashing in that case. This UI method is certainly easier to follow.

Comment: Hi ismirsehregal, I moved sidebar conditional panels out of renderUI and am now getting the invocation flashing in the sidebar panel. Detailed in the question I just posted, "In R shiny, how to eliminate flashing of all conditional panels in sidebar when first invoking the App without using renderUI?"

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement since you are rendering the UI in the server. Alternatively you could create the entire sidebar in the server, gives you a bit more flexibility. You can actually remove the entire conditional panel now and just generate the buttons to use in the UI using the input$tabselected values as conditions, that's up to you.

```
output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", 
      actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates'),
      if(input$tabselected == 4){
        actionButton('test','Test')
      }
      # ATTEMPT # condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test','Test')
    ) # close conditional panel
  }) # close renderUI
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, that places "Test" action button in tab 4 and not in tab 5, as intended. However, before this change, any modifications in tab 4 (by clicking "Modify rates" action button in sidebar and making changes to input grid in modal dialog) were reactively reflected in both tables/plots in tabs 4 and 5, instantly. And vice versa. But with your change, a modification in tab 4 isn't picked up in tab 5 until "Modify rates" is clicked again, and vice versa. Do you know how to restore the reactivity that was there before?

Answer (score 0):

Below is complete MWE code for solving this while still rendering conditional panels in `server` section using `renderUI` (maybe I'm wrong, will test some more, but this `renderUI` method I think resolved some App invocation flashing issues).

Here's the nesting of conditional panels which solved this for me:

```
output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates'),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test', 'Test'),
        ) # close 2nd conditional panel
    ) # close 1st conditional panel
  }) # close renderUI
```

Complete MWE incorporating the above:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x, matrix4Input) {
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix4Input,
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(
      extend = FALSE,
      names = FALSE,
      editableNames = FALSE
    ),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x, y) {
  a <- rep(y, x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)
}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  plot(
    w[, 1],
    sapply(w[, 2], function(x)
      gsub("%", "", x)),
    main = x,
    xlab = y,
    ylab = z
  )
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model..."),
  sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(
    strong("Base Input Panel")
  ))), uiOutput("Panels")),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "Liabilities module",
      value = 4,
      fluidRow(
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "showRates4",
          label = h5(strong(helpText(
            "Select model output to view:"
          ))),
          choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
          selected = 'Rates values',
          inline = TRUE
        ),
        uiOutput('showTab4Results')
      )
    ),
    # close tab panel
    tabPanel(
      "Interest rates",
      value = 5,
      fluidRow(
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "showRates5",
          label = h5(strong(helpText(
            "Select model output to view:"
          ))),
          choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
          selected = 'Rates values',
          inline = TRUE
        ),
        uiOutput('showTab5Results')
      )
    ),
    # close tab panel
    id = "tabselected"
  ))
) # close tabset panel, main panel, page with sidebar

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  matrix4   <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate  <-
    function() {vectorBaseRate(60, input$matrix4[1, 1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates'),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test', 'Test'),
        ) # close 2nd conditional panel
    ) # close 1st conditional panel
  }) # close renderUI
  
  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){DF <- NULL}
    else {
      if (input$modRates < 1) {DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = 0.2)}
      else {
        req(input$matrix4)
        DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = baseRate()[, 2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    DF
  }) # close reactive
  
  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session, 'matrix4', matrix4Default)})
  
  output$table5 <- output$table4 <- renderTable({vectorRates()})
  
  output$graph5 <- output$graph4 <- renderPlot({
    vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(), "A Variable", "Period", "Rate")
  })
  
  output$showTab4Results <- renderUI({
    if (input$showRates4 == 'Rates values'){tableOutput("table4")} 
    else {plotOutput("graph4")}
  })
  
  output$showTab5Results <- renderUI({
    if (input$showRates5 == 'Rates values'){tableOutput("table5")} 
    else {plotOutput("graph5")}
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   matrix4Input("matrix4", if (is.null(input$matrix4))
                     matrix4Default
                     else
                       input$matrix4),
                   useShinyjs(),
                   footer = tagList(
                     actionButton("resetRatesStruct", "Reset"),
                     modalButton("Close")
                   )
                 ))
               } # close modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```